# Swipe between views on ViewController

Tags: xcode, view, keyboard, calculator, swipe

I'm programming a calculator app in which the user is able to add mathematical functions to an array. There is a keyboard at the bottom of my ViewController and above of it there is a view showing the selected function f(x). I know how it's possible to change between different ViewControllers, but how can I change between different functions by only swiping between these little views?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use `UIPageViewController` and all you need to do is display paged views and detect what page is currently on, I would suggest you use `UIScrollView` with paging.

On how add paging in UIScrollView you can read here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html

And the most important part for you, how to detect page changes, you can use this code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    static NSInteger previousPage = 0;
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    float fractionalPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
    NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
    if (previousPage != page) {
        // Page has changed, do your thing!
        // ...
        // Finally, update previous page
        previousPage = page;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for help